# Speed ​up the moving average calculation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The code below considers the moving average, depending on a few conditions. And if the date in the row is less than the specified one (startdate), then it returns the current value of the column. Everything is cool, but it works slowly (i have >200000 rows), can this be accelerated?

```
startdate = pd.to_datetime('2019-06-02')
df['RES1_1Y'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: (df.loc[
        (
            (df.DATE_G < x.DATE_G)
            & (df.DATE_G >= (x.DATE_G + pd.DateOffset(days=-365)))
            & (df.ID1_G == x.ID1_G)
            & (df.ID_C_T == x.ID_C_T)
        ),
        "RES",
    ].mean()) if x.DATE_G > startdate else x.RES1_1Y,
    axis=1,
)
```

Comment: still not found a solution(

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Rolling_mean along with few other functions are grouped in Pandas documentation under the rubric moving window functions.

If this doesn't work, let me know and I can share the code.

Comment: I think, this should work, but I don’t understand how to combine it with the conditions